# Using Pandas Multiindex to find rows where there is more than one unique level 2 index in level 1 meeting a criteria

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a pandas dataframe with heirarchical multiindex of two levels, and a boolean column "Tag". What I want to do is determine if, for each index value in level one, there is only one unique value in level two where "Tag" == True.

In many cases, the index values on level 2 are duplicated, however the data is structured so that the "Tag" values are consistent for every row with the same index value.

```
d = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 
     'File': ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'f'], 
     'Tag': [False, False, True, True, False, True, True, False, False, True]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.set_index(['ID', 'File'], inplace = True)


df
           Tag
ID File       
1  a     False
   a     False
   b      True
   b      True
   c     False
2  d      True
   d      True
   e     False
   e     False
   f      True
```

In this example, I would like to identify files 'd' and 'f' (two different files in the same ID where Tag = True)

Index level 1 is okay because file b is the only file with 'Tag' == True, even though it occurs multiple times.

Alternatively, I could identify the level 1 index where the issue occurs (ID = 2)

I attempted to use DataFrame.duplicated to find duplicate "Tag" values for each index level, but it seems to ignore the index entirely.

```
df.duplicated(keep=False)


ID  File
1   a       True
    a       True
    b       True
    b       True
    c       True
2   d       True
    d       True
    e       True
    e       True
    f       True
dtype: bool
```

Is there a method by which I can find duplicate values in the dataframe for unique levels of the index?

Answer (score 0):

To find the duplicate values in the dataframe for unique levels of the index, first you need to ungroup the dataframe by reset_index():

```
df=df.reset_index()

dup=df[df.duplicated()]
print(dup)  # This will print all duplicate values

   ID   File    Tag
1   1   a   False
3   1   b   True
6   2   d   True
8   2   e   False
```